# preg_replace does not appear to be working am I missing delimiters

Tags: php, regex

I have the following regex which works fine in a regex editor but when I pull it together in PHP i am getting and Unknown modifier '(' error come up.

```
preg_replace("(\[LINK\])(\S*)(\[\/LINK])", "<a>href=\'$2\'>$2</a>", $xtext);
```

This is my first question on SO so I hope I have given enough information. From my research I believe I am missing delimiters but tried ~ at the start and the end of the search pattern and still does not seem to work.

Comment: [Possible duplicate of all these questions...](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+%5Bregex%5D+Unknown+modifier+%27%28%27+is%3Aquestion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
preg_replace("/(\[LINK\])(\S*)(\[\/LINK])/", "<a>href=\'$2\'>$2</a>", $xtext);
```

Note the delimiters

Answer (score 0):

Just try with:

```
$input  = 'foo [LINK]http://google.com[/LINK] bar';
$output = preg_replace('/\[LINK\](.*?)\[\/LINK\]/', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $input);
```

Output:

```
string 'foo <a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a> bar' (length=57)
```

Comment: Thanks, your comment made me realise i had added and additional > after my opening <a tag which removed and with the delimiters added now works.